# What's the best way to do a interactive dashboard with functions running every hour in PHP/Laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, curl, automation, cron

I created a dashboard using PHP/Laravel framework, and 90% of it's functionalities is done. But I need to do somethings that I can't find a proper way to do it, the most close that I found is cronjobs.

- It needs to executes PHP functions that check the server status, api status, access another website and give me the value of the price of bitcoins every minute.

I thought: "I can do it with cURL PHP and Ajax", but the problem is: It needs to run/work in background, even with the website closed.

How should I do it?

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Anyway, take a look at [scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling)

Comment: You can try the [Cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)